# Recover File menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was learning the things in Android Studio which I didn't know . While proceeding with this learning , **File** menu from menu bar has removed by mistake . Now I am searching how to add **File** menu again , I didn't find any setting for this in the Android Studio . I searched it on StackOverflow but no luck .

Help me please I have stuck with this issue .

Here is the snapshot of Android Studio :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Settings]

Enter settings via Hotkey or shift+strg+A then type settings.

In the Settings menue navigate to Appearance & Behaviour > Menus and Toolbars and klick Restore Default in the lower right corner

Comment: Menus and Toobars is not available inside Appearance & Behaviour , how should I find them ?

Comment: added an image for clarification, if you still don't find it maybe reinstall android studio

Comment: I think short cut should be Shift + Ctrl + A .

Answer (score 1):

I am bit late to answer this question but I have working solution for Android Studio 4.1.2

Simply Press Ctrl + Shift + A and type menu and now if see the ON/OFF button in right and simply toggle menu visibility by click
[image: Search menu]